# Como escrevar uma função que recebe 2 números inteiros como parâmetro e devolve o maior deles?

Tags: python

Escreva a função máximo que recebe 2 números inteiros como parâmetro e devolve o maior deles.

exemplo:

```
>>> maximo(3, 4)
4
>>> maximo(0, -1)
0
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Postagem de meros enunciados não atende aos objetivos do site.

Answer (score 4):

Se não puder utilizar a função builtin [max](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max) que devolve o maior item em um iterável ou o maior de dois ou mais argumentos.:

```
>>> max(3, 4) 
4
```

Compare os argumentos para decidir qual o maior e retorne-o.

```
def maior1(n1, n2):
    if n1 > n2:
        return n1
    return n2

def maior2(n1, n2):
    return n1 if n1 > n2 else n2
   
maior3 = lambda n1, n2: n1 if n1 > n2 else n2 

print(maior1(4, 8))        #8

print(maior2(32, 2))       #32

print(maior3(687, 8233))   #8233
```

As três funções `maior1()`, `maior2()` e `maior3()` são equivalentes.

- `maior1()` usa uma [declaração if](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)
- `maior2()` usa uma [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).
- `maior3()` é declarada com uma [expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) e usa uma [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Answer (score -5):

```
def maximo(n1,n2): 
    if n1 > n2:
        print(n1)
    elif n2 > n1:
        print(n2)
    else:
        print(f'{n1} é igual a {n2}')
maximo(0,1)
```

Comment: Atente-se ao detalhe que a sua função não está devolvendo (leia-se retornando) o valor como é solicitado, apenas exibindo-o.

Comment: Outro detalhe: e se `n1` for igual a `n2`?

Comment: por isso eu adicionei um if e um elif, eu poderia ter adicionado um if e um else, mas se eles fossem iguais o maior seria o n2.

Answer (score -7):

Olá!
Tenta esse codigo aqui:

```
def mostra_maior(num1, num2):
    if num1 > num2:
        print(num1)
    else:
        print(num2)

mostra_maior(4,8)
>>> 8
```

Comment: E se você fizer `mostra_maior(8, 4)`, qual será a saída?